# Qt QProcess Complains about QThread::Start , Thread Creation Error

Tags: qt, qthread, qprocess, qtembedded

I have an extremely simple app that is supposed to use QProcess to do some systemd control. Then entire program is below. Every time I run the app, it complains with the following:

```
QThread::start: Thread creation error: Resource temporarily unavailable
```

I print out the max number of threads for one process with _POSIX_THREAD_THREADS_MAX and it prints 64. I can also run the QProcess command on the command line just fine with no issues. What gives?

Code:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);

    // Get the command line parameter to turn wifi on or off
    QString wifiSwitch = argv[1];

    // Print the number of threads available
    qDebug() << "Single Process can spawn this many threads:" << _POSIX_THREAD_THREADS_MAX;

    // Switch based on the input and control wifi with systemctl
    if ( wifiSwitch == "on" ) {

        // Subprocess systemd
        QProcess controlWifi;
        controlWifi.start("systemctl start wiap.service");
        controlWifi.waitForFinished();

        // Grab the output and use it to determine whether we successfully turned on the wifi
        QString didTurnOnWifi = QString(controlWifi.readAll()).trimmed();
        controlWifi.close();

        // So if there is no error messages from the subprocess we were successful
        if ( didTurnOnWifi.length() == 0 ) {
            qDebug() << "SUCCESS";
            exit(0);
        }
        else {
            qDebug() << "FAILURE";
            exit(-1);
        }

    }
    else if ( wifiSwitch == "off" ) {

        // Subprocess systemd
        QProcess controlWifi;
        controlWifi.start("systemctl stop wiap.service");
        controlWifi.waitForFinished();

        // Grab the output and use it to determine whether we successfully turned on the wifi
        QString didTurnOnWifi = QString(controlWifi.readAll()).trimmed();
        controlWifi.close();

        // So if there is no error messages from the subprocess we were successful
        if ( didTurnOnWifi.length() == 0 ) {
            qDebug() << "SUCCESS";
        }
        else {
            qDebug() << "FAILURE";
        }

    }
    else {

        // No arguments
        qDebug() << "FAILURE: You didn't specify any command line arguments, call this program like './fluke-control-wifi on|of'";
        exit(-1);

    }

    return a.exec();
}
```

NOTE: I recently upgraded to Qt 4.8.4 from Qt 4.8.3 but that really shouldn't break QProcess.. I can't find a bug report for that either.

Comment: When in the code is the message reported?

Comment: At this line --> controlWifi.start("systemctl stop wiap.service");

Answer (score 0):

Try adding

```
if(!controlWifi.waitForStarted())
{
    qDebug("Error starting process\n");
    return;
}
```

just after the call to start.